# Windows 7: Different window styles for applications launched as different users

Tags: windows, windows-7

Every user has a domain account without administrative privileges as well as a local account with local administrator privileges. Some users also have access to additional accounts (e.g. a version control administration user, a nightly build service user, etc.).

Generally we work under our non-administrator domain account and supply elevated credentials when required, or manually run applications as administrators or other users where required.

What I'd like to do is change the window style of windows belonging to applications that were launched as different users.

For example:

- I run `cmd.exe` normally, window looks normal.
- I run `cmd.exe` as an
  Administrator, window has a red border or titlebar.

Part of the motivation for this is that it's very common for me to have the same application running with multiple instances as multiple users, and I'd like a better way to keep which belongs to which straight.

Does anybody know if this is possible? Unfortunately I've found the combination of keywords required to ask this question make searching google or stackexchange very, very difficult.